# Testcase and Build is failing with Xgboost-2.0.0

Tags: python, algorithm, github, repository, open-source

While contributing to **The Algorithms/Python**, a GitHub repo for algorithms, I came across an error (https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Python/actions/runs/6256698587/job/16987932045?pr=9074)
Which is happening due to a .py file - https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Python/blob/master/machine_learning/xgboost_regressor.py

Kindly suggest why this testcase is failing as it was correct before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With new version of XGboost-2.0.0, now it uses the `hist` tree method as the default, whereas previously it used `approx` or `exact` methods

See [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/9606#event-10452862416) for detailed answer.